# bacula Device File: is not open. Device is BLOCKED

Tags: bacula

We are trying to set up Bacula.  We have a node that runs Bacula server, a node that is being backed up, and a third node where the backup data is stored.  From the log file, the job is successfully created, storage target connection is set and active.  But when trying to create a volume, get this error:

Device File: "dev11-device" (/backup/bacula/backup) is not open.
Device is BLOCKED waiting to create a volume for:
Pool:        Dev11Pool
Media type:  File
Available Space=30.71 TB

We have spent weeks on this one.. run out of ideas.  Any thoughts?